# centering image vertically in fluid container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="A"> //Fluid Width And Height
Some content..............
</div>

<div id="B">
   <img src='xyz.jpg'>//Fluid Width and Height
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#A {
width:50%;
min-height:50px;
}
#B{
min-height:50px;
}
#B > img {
width:55%;
}
```

What I want is:

1. Div B should always have the same height as Div A.
2. Image inside Div B should be centered vertically in Div B.
3. Way to trigger this code after the Divs A and B have commpletely loaded and their repective   css has been applied.

Fiddle of markup: http://jsfiddle.net/LjyzM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the height of B to the same height as A, then set the top margin of the image to the container height minus the image height divided by two :

```
var h   = $('#A').height(),
    img = $('#B').height(h).find('img');

img.css('margin-top', (h-img.height())/2);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zauN/)

**EDIT:**

to make sure the image is loaded, you can use this trick:

```
$('img', '#B').one('load', function() {
    var h = $('#A').height();

    $('#B').height(h);
    $(this).css('margin-top', ( h - $(this).height() ) / 2);
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

**EDIT AGAIN:**

if you have to wait for more content to load, do:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    var h   = $('#A').height(),
        img = $('#B').height(h).find('img');

    img.css('margin-top', (h-img.height())/2);
});
```

Comment: I tried this approach myself earlier but it fails sometimes. The Divs don't load completely in time or the image doesn't.

Comment: Did you set an actual height attribute on the image ?

Comment: No the height changes dynamically. Should I?

Comment: Yes, normally you should set the height, width and alt attributes of an image. I added an alternative all the same !

Comment: 'The Divs don't load completely in time or the image doesn't' - use it on window load, rather than on DOM ready. should work then.

Comment: You are using fixed heights on everything in the fiddle.

Comment: @user2556089 - Yes I am, as normally you'd set the dimensions of images in the markup, but try waiting for the image to load, like the added code does.

Comment: @nevermind I was using it on window ready...Isn't it alright?

Comment: The window doesn't have a ready handler, only the document does, but you could use window.onload, but a better approach would be to just wait for the image in question to load, and not everything.

Comment: @adeneo i consoled the height of Div A, it changes after a few milliseconds as its content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

```
<div class="something-semantic">
   <div class="something-else-semantic">
       Unknown stuff to be centered.
   </div>
</div>

.something-semantic {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
.something-else-semantic {
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```